# Django: Is there a way to retrieve ORM for past migration states?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-south

Suppose you had a Django model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And you migrate it to:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    both_names = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

You might write a data migration for this case (or mine, not the above, but similar and not cogent to the question) and you would definitely want to test it.

I used `call_command('migrate', app, state)` to roll the database back to the old state and then I thought I'd just use a historic ORM of `Person` to instantiate some `Person` objects, then do the migration, then make some assertions to check if my data migration went properly.

In `South`, you would just call up the old ORM by `Migration`.  How does one do this in `Django 1.8`?

I'm basing my strategy on this documentation: https://micknelson.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/testing-django-migrations/
And I'm hoping to find the implementation for Django's `historic-models`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#historical-models

To restate the question - How would I get the 'old' state of `Person`, such that I would create a person like so: `Person(first_name='bob', last_name='jones')` - for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

The public API doesn't provide any means to get historical models outside of a migration. However, you can get it using the following code:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader

loader = MigrationLoader(connection)
state = loader.project_state(loader.applied_migrations)
apps = state.apps
```

`apps` is the same object that is passed to the function in a `RunPython` operation. You can get a historical model for the currently applied migrations using `apps.get_model('<app_label>', '<ModelName>')`.

This should work in 1.8 and 1.9. It may or may not work in future versions, though I see little reason why this part of the API should change anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

For Django 3.0 and 3.1 , the solution is mostly the same as the answer from @knbk , except the input argument to `project_state()` is simply a tuple like `('<APP_LABEL>', '<MIGRATION_NAME>')`  instead of entire `applied_migrations` dictionary.

you can get the state from initial migration to the specific committed migration of specified application, by directly specifying `<APP_LABEL>` or `<MIGRATION_NAME>` like this :

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader

loader = MigrationLoader(connection)
state = loader.project_state(('your_app_label', '0023_alter_some_fields'))
apps = state.apps
```

Note that the code above cannot be used when running migration commands (e.g. `makemigrations`, `sqlmigrate`, `migrate`), otherwise it will cause recursive callstack error.